# Querying HealthKit's correlations, but using anchor

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

My app is basically gathering a lot o info from `HealthKit` and later it uses mathematical models to analyze data and provide us with feedback.
One of many *samples* we're interested in is **blood pressure**, but `HealthKit` is treating this as `HKCorrelationTypeIdentifierBloodPressure` - a set of related `HKSample`s which, in this case are, `HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBloodPressureDiastolic` and `HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBloodPressureSystolic`.

We're gathering all *samples* and for this I'm using `HKAnchoredObjectQuery` but this one accepts only one `HKSampleType`. Pn the other hand, if I use `HKCorrelationQuery` I have to specify dates range for this query which doesn't satisfy my requirements... And here I am, stuck with no good solution.

---

The simplest solution, maybe not the prettiest one, is to create a `dispatch_group` and as separately for **diastolic** and **systolic** samples. When I get them, try to merge two arrays based on `startDate` and `endDate`... Phew! From what I can see in Health.app, user is able to enter correlation at once, so this should be doable based on dates.

Another one that just came into my mind... Maybe it's possible to create `HKAnchoredObjectQuery` and pass `HKCorrelationType` as parameter?

Comment: HKCorrelationType is a subclass of HKSampleType, so it's valid to provide an HKCorrelationType as the type for HKAnchoredObjectQuery.  Have you tried that already?

Comment: First thing in the morning tomorrow... But what I'm worried about is that `HKCorrelation` has objects property which is `Set<HKSample>` but I need some sort of tuple of samples like `(diastolic, systolic)`...

Comment: Examine the sampleType property of each of the members of the correlation to determine which is the systolic sample and which is the diastolic.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Allan for some hints I was able to do this using `HKAnchoredObjectQuery`.
Everything's because `HKCorrelationType` is a subclass of `HKObjectType`, so you can actually pass any correlation to every general purpose method in `HealthKit` which requires `HKObjectType`.

There was one additional concern about this solution - fact that `HKAnchoredQuery` returns `[HKSample]?` but we want to determine **systolic** and **diastolic** but this turned out to be solved by `HealthKit` as well... In return we get `[HKCorrelation]?` and each element has property `objects`, which is `Set<HKSample>`, so we don't have to worry about getting everything mixed up and we can easily cast the results to any method accepting `HKSample` by simply checking `sampleType` property.

Comment: Hi Cojoj, I am also trying to use HKAnchoredObjectQuery for blood pressure Correlation type query but not getting any response. Can you please help me out.

Here is the code I'm using:
let bloodpressureType = HKQuantityType.correlationTypeForIdentifier(HKCorrelationTypeIdentifierBloodPressure)

 let anchoredQuery = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: bloodpressureType, predicate: predicate, anchor: hkAnchor, limit: 0, resultsHandler: onAnchorQueryResults)

But I am not getting any result from the query.